# ObjectContext error accessing to related entity obtained in stored procedure (EF 4)

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-4.1, relationship

I have the following store procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_BuscarBien_servicio]
@campo varchar(50),
@numPags int,
@numRegs int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP (@numRegs) 
        [Project1].[BS_Id] AS [BS_Id], 
        [Project1].[BS_Descripcion] AS [BS_Descripcion], 
        [Project1].[UNM_Id] AS [UNM_Id], 
        [Project1].[BS_CostoPromedio] AS [BS_CostoPromedio], 
        [Project1].[BSTIP_Id] AS [BSTIP_Id], 
        [Project1].[UNM_Id1] AS [UNM_Id1], 
        [Project1].[UNM_Descripcion] AS [UNM_Descripcion], 
        [Project1].[BSTIP_Id1] AS [BSTIP_Id1], 
        [Project1].[BSTIP_Descripcion] AS [BSTIP_Descripcion]
        FROM ( 
            SELECT [Project1].[BS_Id] AS [BS_Id], 
                   [Project1].[BS_Descripcion] AS [BS_Descripcion], 
                   [Project1].[UNM_Id] AS [UNM_Id], 
                   [Project1].[BS_CostoPromedio] AS [BS_CostoPromedio], 
                   [Project1].[BSTIP_Id] AS [BSTIP_Id], 
                   [Project1].[UNM_Id1] AS [UNM_Id1], 
                   [Project1].[UNM_Descripcion] AS [UNM_Descripcion], 
                   [Project1].[BSTIP_Id1] AS [BSTIP_Id1], 
                   [Project1].[BSTIP_Descripcion] AS [BSTIP_Descripcion], 
                   row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[BS_Descripcion] ASC) AS [row_number]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Extent1].[BS_Id] AS [BS_Id], 
                    [Extent1].[BS_Descripcion] AS [BS_Descripcion], 
                    [Extent1].[UNM_Id] AS [UNM_Id], 
                    [Extent1].[BS_CostoPromedio] AS [BS_CostoPromedio], 
                    [Extent1].[BSTIP_Id] AS [BSTIP_Id], 
                    [Extent2].[UNM_Id] AS [UNM_Id1], 
                    [Extent2].[UNM_Descripcion] AS [UNM_Descripcion], 
                    [Extent3].[BSTIP_Id] AS [BSTIP_Id1], 
                    [Extent3].[BSTIP_Descripcion] AS [BSTIP_Descripcion]
                    FROM   [dbo].[Bien_servicio] AS [Extent1]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Unidad_Medida] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[UNM_Id] = [Extent2].[UNM_Id]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Bs_tipo] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[BSTIP_Id] = [Extent3].[BSTIP_Id]
                    WHERE [Extent1].[BS_Descripcion] like '%'+ @campo + '%'
                    or [Extent2].[UNM_Descripcion] like '%'+ @campo + '%'
                    or [Extent1].[BS_CostoPromedio] like '%'+ @campo + '%'
                    or [Extent3].[BSTIP_Descripcion] like '%'+ @campo + '%'
                )  AS [Project1]
        )  AS [Project1]
        WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > (@numPags - 1)*@numRegs
        ORDER BY [Project1].[BS_Descripcion] ASC
END
```

Which is imported in this function:

```
public static List<Bien_servicio> ListarBien_servicio(int numPags, int numRegs, String campo = "")
{
    try
    {
        using (SampleDBEntities db = new SampleDBEntities())
        {
           return db.BuscarBien_servicio(campo, numPags, numRegs).ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
 }
```

Using the following relations

Bs_tipo --< Bien_servicio >--- Unidad_Medida

When I try to obtain a related entity (Bien_Servicio.Bs_Tipo) I get the error: "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection"

In db layer, related entities are mapped correctly, but in winform code I get this exception like I lost a connection.

This happens in stored procedure (if I use db.Bien_Servicio.Include("Bs_tipo").ToList(); I have no problem). Even if I convert the result in .ToList(). What is my error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lazy loading issue. You do load the `Bien_Servicio` list, but not the related references. So when the consumer of your `ListarBien_servicio` method tries to access `Bien_Servicio.Bs_Tipo` the context is gone, giving the exception you mention.

So how to load the related entities? You can't load them in your call to the stored procedure because stored procedures are not composable (which means so much as: there is no way to translate a `join` into sql). So there is no way for `ObjectResult` to support `Include` because it involves joining and neither can you use join in linq.

You'll have to [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738874.aspx) the `Bs_Tipo` references manually within the `using` scope of the context. Or you should have your stored procedure return `BS_Id` values only and use the Id's to `Select` the full records from `db.Bien_Servicio` (with an `Include`).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using Load:

```
var x = (from b in db.BuscarBien_servicio(campo, numPags, numRegs)
        select b).ToList();
foreach (Bien_servicio b in x)
{
     b.Unidad_MedidaReference.Load();
     b.Bs_tipoReference.Load();
}
return x;
```

Instead of

```
return db.BuscarBien_servicio(campo, numPags, numRegs).ToList();
```